# Its possible finish method inside nested method?

Tags: php

How can I make the code only run if the string is not **hello**

```
class Foo {
    public function simpleMethod($str) {
        if ($str === "hello") {
            $this->bar($str);
            // Its possible dont write here 'return'
        }
        echo "this code always works... but how can i do for that only work if str is not 'hello'";
    }
    private function bar($str) {
        // do awesome stuff...
        // 
        // If this method was called $str should be 'hello'
        // so i want that when this method finish ALL parents method finish too.. 
        // And the next line executed will be '$f->simpleMethod("airport");'
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
$f->simpleMethod("tree");
$f->simpleMethod("hello");
$f->simpleMethod("airport");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a simple `else` statement:

```
public function simpleMethod($str) {
    if ($str === "hello") {
        $this->bar($str);
        // Its possible dont write here 'return'
    } else {
        echo "only get here if str is not 'hello'";
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew that statement.. but my code is more longer than the example.. if i use 'else' my code will be very ugly, so i think that i use a simple 'return'

Comment: I see - from what I understood, you didn't want a `return` statement: "// Its possible dont write here 'return'"

Comment: I dont want write return... but i prefer return instead of else.. i ask if exist a command(¿?) that to finish the main method inclusive if im in a nested method. But i think that no. Sorry for my english again

Comment: No you only have 2 options: 1) let the function finish normally (by hiding other code in an `else` block), 2) exit by using the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

simple you need like this

```
class Foo {
    public function simpleMethod($str) {
        if ($str === "hello") {
            $this->bar($str);
            // Its possible dont write here 'return'
        }
        else{
         echo "this code always works... but how can i do for that only work if str is not 'hello'";
        }

    }
    private function bar($str) {
        // do awesome stuff...
        // 
        // If this method was called $str should be 'hello'
        // so i want that when this method finish ALL parents method finish too.. 
        // And the next line executed will be '$f->simpleMethod("airport");'
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
//$f->simpleMethod("tree");
$f->simpleMethod("hello");
$f->simpleMethod("airport");
```